# Export Hadoop output to text files

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

After I run some sample Map Reduce programs I check the output with a command like this:
`hdfs -cat \usr\cloudera\output\part-r-0000`

And it looks something like this:

[image]

I was wondering how to export it as a text or csv for further analysis.  I want to put the data into excel for anlysis. I'm using Cloudera VM for Hadoop.

I did a `hdfs -get \usr\cloudera\output\part-r-0000 \somewhere\results.txt` but it messed the contents.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to modify the code.  By changing the reducer to write a comma between the two values you'll get the data in CSV format.

Of course, it looks like the data is already in TSV (tab separated format), something most spreadsheets understand.

As for getting the data out of HDFS, try

```
hdfs -cat \usr\cloudera\output\part-r-0000 >\somewhere\results.txt
```